# How secure is this mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Previously I used general `mysqli` queries to insert values in database with `real_escape_string` for security but everyone seems to use prepared statements for better security. To increase security and prevent sql injection I am going to replace my code with prepared statements but I wanted to know that how much secure is prepared statement given below. Can you suggest any more improvement for better security?

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($DB_connection,"INSERT INTO `posts`(`example`, `example2`) VALUES ('$for_example',?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['username']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

I get values from a form using POST method and add them to database. Can users replace values in database by sql injection?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What is `$for_example`?

Comment: I'll replace `$for_example` with session variable like this `$_SESSION['username']` etc

Answer (score 2):

From PHP manual:

> The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the
>   driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively uses
>   prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection
>   will occur (however, if other portions of the query are being built up
>   with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).

Reference: [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

You ARE building your query with (possibly) unescaped input. It all depends whether or not `$for_example` is safe...

Therefore, my suggestion would be to include `$for_example` as a parameter in your prepared statement.

Comment: `$for_example` is session variable.

Comment: But is it user input or not?

Comment: It is from database if user is logged in.

Comment: I wish I could unsee the last comment.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: you're right. For future references, I've deleted my comment. It's best that said variable would also be passed through as a parameter.